# Swagger ui json import in Swagger editor gives error: Undocumented TypeError: Failed to fetch on making API calls

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a small spring boot project in which I have configured swagger UI for generating the endpoint that shows the API documentation for my project controller methods. If I run my project locally, and I access: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html then, it works perfectly fine and I can see the documentation of my project APIs. I can also make API calls on this page using the try it out button.

Now I access (my app is still running locally): http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs and it gives me a JSON and I save this in my system.

Now, I open the swagger editor (just by accessing https://editor.swagger.io/) and then I import the previously downloaded JSON. It shows me the API documentation but now If I click to try it out, it gives me an error: **Undocumented TypeError: Failed to fetch**

How to fix this? If I give this JSON to anyone, how will they ever test my API?

Comment: What's the error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: This is what i see in console tab of chrome: Access to fetch at 'https://localhsot:8080/students from origin 'https://editor.swagger.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.